# Webscraping with scrapy : empty results

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am learning how to use scrappy, i would like to extract some youtube video links from this [website](https://research.google.com/audioset///eval/baby_cry_infant_cry.html). I have written this script to extract the links from the website to a json file.

```
import scrapy
class getVideos(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'wbScraper'
    start_urls = ['https://research.google.com/audioset///eval/baby_cry_infant_cry.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        for url in response.xpath("//div[@class='thumbnail_container']"): 
            yield {
                    'video_url': url.xpath(".//div[@class='u']").extract_first()
```

I just get an empty reponse (as shown on the image below). I have tried on another website and it worked very well, it is the second result. 
[The results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzlRA.png)

Could you help me with this problem ? The xpath seems correct ...

Comment: Most likely the videos are added dynamically. So when the web page is loaded, the container is empty initially.

Answer (score 0):

The videos are not in the html of the original request. Rather, a second request is made after the first page is loaded which brings in the videos.

Good news is that the URL for the videos is easy to find, and the result is in a simple format. The file contains the YouTube video ID and the tags of the video.

https://storage.googleapis.com/audioset_website_data/youtube_corpus/v1/eval/baby_cry_infant_cry/1.js

And here is an example of the file from that URL.

```
["2TV2DW0bzBg", 0.0, 8.0, [["Baby cry, infant cry", "baby_cry_infant_cry"]]], 
["2eWobSpugTw", 17.0, 27.0, [["Baby cry, infant cry", "baby_cry_infant_cry"]]], 
["2fKgYlCx_As", 26.0, 36.0, [["Crying, sobbing", "crying_sobbing"], ["Speech", "speech"], ["Baby cry, infant cry", "baby_cry_infant_cry"]]], 
["3KwulXmBX-8", 30.0, 40.0, [["Baby cry, infant cry", "baby_cry_infant_cry"]]], 
["4KxLSx-EhHI", 0.0, 9.0, [["Speech", "speech"], ["Baby cry, infant cry", "baby_cry_infant_cry"]]],
```